# Is there any way to add the related products simultaneously?

Tags: products-management, product-relations

i have added a products in the magento store. and now i want to add the related products in each of the products. problem is that, i am adding the products one by one for each product and it is taking a lot of time as i have hundreds of products in the store. 
Is there any way to add the related products directly on each and every products. any help will be grateful.

Answer (score 2):

You can [find here an extension](https://github.com/tzyganu/ProductRelationsImport) that let's you bulk upload (or manually insert) product relations (upsell, crossell, related, and with some simple code changes you can add custom relations if you have any).
[This explains how to use it.](https://github.com/tzyganu/ProductRelationsImport/blob/master/README.md).

You can create a csv file with product skus or ids to be related and their position in the relation:

```
34,55:2,17:4
99:1,80:10
```

What is after `:` means the position of the product in the relation.
You can perform 3 different actions:

- Relate all on one line to first product in line.
- Relate all products on one line
- Relate all products among themselves

Answer (score 0):

This is a useful link for programatically set related , upsell and crosssell products [Link](http://marius-strajeru.blogspot.com/2010/06/adding-related-products-up-sells-and.html)

Comment: Posting a link is not a good practice. Tomorrow the remote page is gone and your answer is not valid anymore. Please copy at least the main idea of the solution you linked into your answer. Even though the article is very small.